# Node-Exceljs problem in using sub-property of a Model as Exceljs column key

Tags: node.js, exceljs

I am using exceljs in Node to prepare an Excel file on server. This works fine when the first level properties of a model are used as column keys. But when the second level property of a Model is used as a column key, the column appears blank when the excel file gets downloaded.

Pls see the below code in Node. When I console log docChecks, the defaultersResults.remarks and defaultersResults.resRemarks properties have values but it is not reflecting in excel file. All other property values are getting populated in excel.

Not sure if there is any limitation on using column key in exceljs when it comes to using sub properties such as defaultersResults.resRemarks

Where am I going wrong?

```
  const docChecks = await DocCheck.find({ '_id': { $in: ids } })
    .select('clientName name checkedOn checkSummary defaultersResults.remarks defaultersResults.resRemarks ebiRemarks ebiResRemarks kRemarks kResRemarks nRemarks nResRemarks -_id')
    .lean().exec();

  console.log(docChecks);

  let wb = new Excel.Workbook();
  let ws = wb.addWorksheet('xReport')

  ws.columns = [
    { header: "Name", key: "name", width: 20 },
    { header: "Checked On", key: "checkedOn", width: 20 },
    { header: "Summary", key: "checkSummary", width: 20 },
    { header: "Defaulters Remarks", key: "defaultersResults.remarks", width: 20 },  // NOT populated
    { header: "Defaulters Resolution Remarks", key: "defaultersResults.resRemarks", width: 20 },  // NOT populated
    { header: "EBI Remarks", key: "ebiRemarks", width: 20 },
    { header: "EBI Resolution Remarks", key: "ebiResRemarks", width: 20 },
    { header: "K Remarks", key: "kRemarks", width: 20 },
    { header: "K Resolution Remarks", key: "kResRemarks", width: 20 },
    { header: "N Remarks", key: "nRemarks", width: 20 },
    { header: "N Resolution Remarks", key: "nResRemarks", width: 20 },
  ];

....
```

Comment: can you find any solution? I am in save issue

Comment: I coukd not find any solution within exceljs. So this is the workaround i used. First create a copy of the array such that i bring the required sub-properties as the first-level property, and then use the new array to generate excel sheet.